# What for in @vue/cli 4.0.5 app 2 "app" divs?

Tags: vuejs2

In my @vue/cli 4.0.5 app in  /public/index.html file I see code with div id=“app”

```
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but vtasks doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app" style=" ></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
```

That is clear, but in /src/App.vue file I also see div with “app” id:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
...
```

That is very confusing, what for 2 "app" divs? Making some changes with div in /public/index.html I see that it is rendered in my page here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that webpack (what vue-cli uses) compiles your vue files is *into* the `index.html` file so of course you will have the same `app` basically webpack takes your app from the `App.vue` and compiles it into the `index.html`.
Generally speaking you don't want to be making changes to a vue app from the index file rather from the vue files.